# How to specify .NET version for .NET 4 C# compiler from microsoft?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, c#-4.0

I want to compile a .NET 2.0 DLL by means CSharpCodeProvider from Microsoft .NET 4.0 Runtime.
Is this possible?

By the way, Mono C# compiler can do it. using `sdk` parameter (2 and 4 supported).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 options.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0");
 CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
```

See: [CSharpCodeProvider Constructor (IDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb537926.aspx).